# Low fps on gaming

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, minecraft

today I installed Ubuntu and I tried to play Minecraft
I used to have around 300fps On Windows 7
On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit I Have 30fps very stable
what is wrong?

I'm using this driver:
- "Using Nvidia Binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331(proprietary-tested)"

Comment: Well.. we need more information. From what you are saying I predict that it has something to do with video drivers.

Comment: I have updated the driver that I'm currently Using

Answer (score 0):

What is the nvidia model number and are running dual graphics?

I had a similar problem when using proprietary drivers from the software center for a nvidia 740M. I got 60fps running;

```
glxgears
```

What solved my problem was to remove all nvidia drivers and add the repository;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install;

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 virtualgl
```

this installed the 319 and the latest drivers from xrog-edgers.

running;

```
glxgears
```

i got 1375fps